# Hugo: can I apply a custom css style to a specific post?

Tags: css, hugo

The `css` properties of a post are related to `post` and `post-content` classes if I am not wrong so if I override some of their properties this will apply to all posts in my site.

I would like to apply apply some `css` properties only to a particular post, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1: extra css file

The nicest way to do this is with [page resources](https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-resources/). You can walk over the files in the [page bundle](https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-bundles/) and look for a CSS file. You should then add the CSS file to your head/content using:

```
{{ with .Resources.GetMatch "*.css" }}
  <style>{{ .Content | safeCSS }}</style>
{{ end }}
```

### Solution 2: body class

A simpler (but messier) way is to add a class to your body. This looks like this:

```
<body class="{{ File.BaseFileName }}">
```

This will add a class to the body with the slug of your page. This way you can apply page specific styling, by adding rules to your main stylesheet.